# Ignore specific rows from a table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with data like this:

```
ND
10212121
10232323
10212323
212526 
295652
232565
```

I would like make a select to all ND from this table excluding these starting with 10...using openquery to a oracle database.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following query I check the first two characters of the `ND` column and compare against `10` to see if they be equal.  You did not mention whether or not `ND` is a numeric type, so I added a cast to `varchar2` so that the substring will work.

```
SELECT ND
FROM yourTable
WHERE SUBSTR(CAST(ND AS varchar2(30)), 1, 2) <> '10'
```